# couch.js allDocs() always returns same result

Tags: javascript, windows-8, couchdb

I'm developing an application for Windows 8 using Javascript.  I'm using couchDB as a data provider with the couch.js wrapper.

If I access my existing database "test" like this:

```
CouchDB.urlPrefix = "http://127.0.0.1:5984";
var db = new CouchDB("test");
var docs = db.allDocs();
var changes = db.changes();
var thing = {};
db.save(thing);
var docs2 = db.allDocs();
var changes2 = db.changes();
```

Then docs == docs2 and changes == changes2, even though "thing" is saved correctly.  This does not seem right to me.  What am I doing wrong?  I went through the couch.js methods and they seem to be generating the correct request.

Comment: Is couch.js caching the results? Can you confirm that, if you go to `http://127.0.0.1:5984/test/<thing.id>` that the document exists?

Comment: Yes, the save function works just as it should.  I can confirm it in my browser when stepping through it using breakpoints.

Comment: I am not referring to the `save` method. I am asking if, when you hit the CouchDb URL with the database name and id for thing, does anything appear? Does the network request succeed?

Comment: Yes.  The request succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE aggressively caches, and since the request is the same the second time it just gives you the result from the first time around.

This has been fixed in jquery.couch.js, but not in couch.js.

The fix is to append something to the end of the request that makes it unique.

I did "?_=" + Date.now().